# Easiest way to transfer files from iPhone to Linux?

Tags: iphone, unix, file-transfer

What's the easiest way to transfer files from an iPhone to a non-Apple computer such as one running Linux?

Comment: What is the kind of file you are looking to transfer?

Comment: @NimeshNeema Any kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [VLC](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id650377962?mt=8) (free, open-source). Share/copy files to the VLC folder. Then enable WiFi sharing in VLC. Navigate to the phone's URL.

This only works for video files, though.

<sup>courtesy [Anshul Choudhary](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232376/202217)</sup>