# Batch moving voice memos to Linux PC

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, apple-watch, voice-memo

I have over 600 of voice memos on iPhone 2020 SE (actually recorded on Apple Watch) ranging from a few seconds to a couple of minutes. How do I batch move them to a Linux PC, having the date of recording info without the woes of manually ticking 600 files? I've tried just selecting them and sending to Dropbox, but that is painfully unreliable:

- Dropbox does not synchronize more than 10 files at once,
- few out of those 10 are just left behind and unsynchronized by Dropbox,
- the date of recording is lost when copying files this way.

**UPD** Using answers from [How can I transfer large files from Linux to iPad over a cable or wifi?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6221/374681) didn't help:

- `ideviceinfo` keeps saying "ERROR: No device found!"
- Using third-party file managers is futile since they can't "see" the recording files, those are considered some other kind of files by iOS for some reason.
- FileMaster app actually can share the files "sent" to it, but then again, I'd have to tick 600 hundred files to send the files into FileMaster and then click 600 hundred times in its web UI to download the files. My question is focused on **batch** aspect of transferring.

Answer (score 0):

On the screen listing the recordings, you can switch to multi-select by tapping with two fingers, and then use the share button at bottom left to copy all of them to Files (and from there to a mounted SMB drive).

PS: Still a pain, but maybe a smaller one. Also not sure the recording date is preserved.